# Can not find out WHY jmxRemoteURL contains non-ASCII character

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, jmx, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to use Tomcat (v: 9.0.12) with Intellij Idea (v: 2018.3) for deploying an Artifact (A simple hello world javaEE web application project).

This is some of my outputs after Building and Starting the project (I am gonna put these outputs for some useful information. also you can find the FULL outputs at the end of my question) :

```
"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\catalina.bat" run
[2019-09-07 10:58:59,049] Artifact test:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\pcs\.IntelliJIdea2018.3\system\tomcat\Tomcat_9_0_12_test"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.net.MalformedURLException: Service URL contains non-ASCII character 0x6f1
```

After that I have an error with *JMX* and if I'll be right it occurs at : "jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer" (**ConnectorBootstrap.java:491**).

#### I've put the full output at the end.

Before asking my question would you please take look at some parts of **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\lib\src.zip!\java.management\javax\management\remote\JMXServiceURL.java**
and as you will see it's making sure that there are no non-ASCII characters in the URL and there is a part of my answer in it :

```
public class JMXServiceURL implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8173364409860779292L;

    /**
     * Constructs a JMXServiceURL by parsing a Service URL
     * string.
     *
     * @param serviceURL the URL string to be parsed.
     *
     * @exception NullPointerException if  serviceURL is
     * null.
     *
     *  @exception MalformedURLException if serviceURL
     * does not conform to the syntax for an Abstract Service URL or
     * if it is not a valid name for a JMX Remote API service.  A
     * JMXServiceURL must begin with the string
     * "service:jmx:" (case-insensitive).  It must not
     * contain any characters that are not printable ASCII characters.
     */
    public JMXServiceURL(String serviceURL) throws MalformedURLException {
        final int serviceURLLength = serviceURL.length();

        /* Check that there are no non-ASCII characters in the URL,
           following RFC 2609.  */
        for (int i = 0; i < serviceURLLength; i++) {
            char c = serviceURL.charAt(i);
            if (c < 32 || c >= 127) {
                throw new MalformedURLException("Service URL contains " +
                                                "non-ASCII character 0x" +
                                                Integer.toHexString(c));
            }
        }
```

You can find ***@exception MalformedURLException*** in comment and the *interesting part* is I can see my Exception message is being ready for me :)

### My Question is : How can I find out about my jmxRemoteURL value which contains non-ASCII character?

Here's what I have already tested :

- I have tried adding "127.0.0.1 localhost hostname" to the end of hosts file which wasn't useful and I can't see any relations between my problem and that.
- I have tried running Intellij Idea as Administrator which also didn't work.

*FINALLY This is my FULL output in Intellij Idea Console :

```
"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\catalina.bat" run
[2019-09-07 10:58:59,049] Artifact test:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\pcs\.IntelliJIdea2018.3\system\tomcat\Tomcat_9_0_12_test"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.net.MalformedURLException: Service URL contains non-ASCII character 0x6f1
jdk.internal.agent.AgentConfigurationError: java.net.MalformedURLException: Service URL contains non-ASCII character 0x6f1
    at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:491)
    at jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:450)
    at jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:621)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Service URL contains non-ASCII character 0x6f1
    at java.management/javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL.<init>(JMXServiceURL.java:157)
    at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.exportMBeanServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:846)
    at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:479)
    ... 2 more
Disconnected from server
```

Please let me know if I missed something to say.
Thanks a lot for your big help.

Comment: You can add `#com.intellij.javaee.jmxremote` in Help | Debug Log Settings, reproduce the issue and check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for more details. Maybe you'll find which part of the URL contains non-ASCII char.

Comment: Thank you I’ll try that and let you know. I just realized 0x6f1 is my non-ASCII part of url! I tried converting it to decimal and binary. It means 1777 in decimal. I’m doing a research about this. I hope I’ll find out.

Comment: Yes, see [EXTENDED ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT ONE](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder?encoding=numeric&bytes=0xe0%200x9b%200xb1).

Comment: Holyyy moly :O I was killing myself about this! You are totally right i JUST realize that 2mins ago with converting int to char (ASCII) with some java code and I found ARABIC DIGIT ONE! I’m trying to remove ARABIC format from my pc! THANKS! :))))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little depth look and doing some researches, I realized ( 0x6f1 ) equals with ( 1777 ) by converting 
Hexadecimal to Decimal online. It seems there is a non-ASCII character which its ( char to *int* ) converted result is 1777.

Finally by converting ( int to *char* ) I realized that the char was actually a non-ASCII :)

(As [CrazyCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104891/crazycoder) found out) it was [EXTENDED ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT ONE](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder?encoding=numeric&bytes=0xe0%200x9b%200xb1)

My **SOLUTION:** I removed *Persian (Standard)* language from my windows OS at:**Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Language**

- Here is ( int to *char* ) java code for who wants to know :

```
int a = 1777;
char c = (char)a;
System.out.println (c);
```

Answer (score 5):

It fixed for me by changing Windows *Regional Format* from Persian to English.